# Save categories of graduated symbols, but not their values in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis

I have about 100 vector layers of different months and years showing EVI anomalies based on county boundaries in Germany. When I use graduated symbology (equal count, 5 classes) for each layer I get a nice map of Germany showing the counties in different colours depending on the EVI anomaly. Now the problem is, that the 5 classes are created depending on the max and min value of each specific vector file and since each month has different max and min values of anomalies, I get different classifications. So the colours are actually misleading when I compare the vector layers with each other. How can I get the same classification for each layer? I have tried to save the style of one layer and applied it to another layer, but then the second layer has the same values as the style layer, i.e. I end up with two identically looking layers - which is not what I want.

Comment: Maybe you should give some more information and ideally a screenshot to be able to understand what exactely you want to do. If I nderstood you well, than a possible solution could be to define in one layer a graduated style with manually defined min/max values - both corresponding to the overall min/max valueas of all your layers. If you have layer1 with min/max 4 to 12 and layer2 with min/max 1 to 9, you should use a range of min 1 to 12.Than you can copy/paste the style to all other layers. Does this help?

Comment: Thanks, yes that's exactly what I wanted/meant. I tried that method before, but I thought it's rather tedious for over 100 layers and hoped that there was a quicker method available - but maybe there isn't anything yet (at least in QGIS)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't understand you correctly: what is the tedious part of your workflow? You set the style once for only one layer and than copy this style to all other layers. Do we speak of something that looks similar to that: https://tinyurl.com/yary5489 ? In this case, in the very first layer (march 03) you define a style with overall min/max of -0.2 to +0.21, even though you don't have this max-value in this particular image. Than copy this style to all other layers. If this is not what you were looking for, give more information and ideally a screenshot.

Comment: So every picture will have just a part of the whole color-spectrum of the used color ramp represented, according to the range inside the overall min/max of each image.